# Вывести заданное количество элементов массива начиная с заданого индекса

Tags: c#, массивы

Добрый день.

Нужно вывести заданное количество элементов с массива начиная с заданного индекса.

Например у нас есть массив с числами 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

и есть 2 переменные `count` и `index`

Допустим count = 2, a index = 3;
Тогда нужно вывести значения массива 5,6.
Подскажите пожалуйста как лучше это сделать?
Заданное число элементов вывожу так :

`mas.Take(count)`

А как добавить еще вывод с определенного индекса ? 
Спасибо!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Используйте все возможности LINQ!

```
arr.Skip(index).Take(count)
```

Comment: Лаконично.

Comment: @teanЫЧ: спасибо, стараюсь.

Answer (score 2):

навскидку:

```
     public int[] GetNumbersFromArray(int index, int count, int[] mas)
     {
        int[] a = new int[count];
        int i = index, y = 0;

        try
        {
            for (; i < index + count; i++, y++)
                a[y] = mas[i]; 
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfRangeException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Попытка прочитать число за границей массива");
        }

        return a;
     }
```